# Delete documents within a collection cloud firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i am using the following tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data to delete all the documents within a collection while offline.
The problem I have is that `Tasks.await(batch.commit());` blocks and not return while offline. As I understand from here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch, WirteBatch operations should work offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say an operation "works offline" it may not mean what you think it means.

The results of a `WriteBatch` performed offline will be immediately reflected in any listeners or `get()` operations that you perform. So if you delete a document in a write batch and then try to read it later (while still offline) it will appear to be deleted.

However the `Task` will not complete until the write batch has been propagated to the server.

Comment: Hi @hatboysam. So this means that `batch.commit()` will be immediate and `Tasks.await(...)` will wait for the backend and therefore will not work while offline. Is that right?

Comment: @edmond yes that's the idea.  `batch.commit()` will immediately affect the offline document cache.